# Can't connect from Debian VM to Windows Server VM

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, ansible-playbook

I've got a problem while trying to configure my Ansible server to connect to a Windows host using ssh keys.

When I try this command :

ansible win -m win_ping

I never got an answer, even after few minutes. But, when I try to debug using -vvv, I don't see any problem in the trace. So, I tried to copy the ssh command that has been executed and... it works.

[fail but success when I manually use the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEgK7.png)

Do you know where can the issue be and how to resolve it ?

Thanks

I try to connect to a Windows host using Ansible and ssh keys.

The thing I don't understand is why I don't get any answer after my Ansible command. I don't have any error even with -vvv so I'm a bit surprised.

Comment: What is odd here is that the SSH command you manually ran shouldn't have given you a prompt.  It should have basically done a `cmd /c "echo ~Administrator`.